# Breeze.js - complex properties cause circular structure exception during em.exportEntities

Tags: breeze

When running exportEntities, breeze does some magic to flatten entities, by removing their properties and popping them in to arrays. In entities with only simple properties, this prevents circular references as the entityAspect is not copied across. However, complex properties are not flattened and still have this entityAspect, leading to a circular structure exception when breeze attempts to call JSON.stringify();

Here's some code to replicate this issue:

```
var jsonMetadata = {
    "metadataVersion": "1.0.3",
    "dataServices": [
        {
            "serviceName": "api/Foo/",
            "hasServerMetadata": false,
            "jsonResultsAdapter": "webApi_default",
            "useJsonp": false
        }
    ],
    "structuralTypes": [
        {
            "shortName": "address",
            "namespace": "YourNamespace",
            "isComplexType": true,
            "dataProperties": [
                {  "name": "street", "dataType": "String" },
                {  "name": "city", "dataType": "String" },
                {  "name": "country", "dataType": "String" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "shortName": "person",
            "namespace": "YourNamespace",
            "dataProperties": [
                {  "name": "id", "dataType": "Int32", isPartOfKey: true },
                {  "name": "name", "dataType": "String" },
                {  "name": "hobbies", "dataType": "String" },
                {  "name": "address", "complexTypeName": "address:#YourNamespace" }
            ] }
    ]
};

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager();
manager.metadataStore.importMetadata(jsonMetadata)

var person = manager.createEntity('person', {id: 1});
person.address.street = "Sample Street";

console.log("Complex property is a circular datatype, cannot convert to JSON - that's fine")
// JSON.stringify(person.address); // fails with error

console.log("... except that manager.exportEntities() doesn't handle that case!");
manager.exportEntities(); // also fails
```

Edit: woops, poor form, left out the question: is this a bug?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Good repro.. thx, I am looking at it now and will repost when I have answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed in Breeze v 1.3.5, available now via nuget and the Breeze web site.

and ... good repro. We appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt fix & reply - testing it out now!